# How can I change a GTK textview's color gradually?

Tags: python, animation, textview, gtk3

I have a GTK TextView with some text in it. I defined a tag that when applied, changes the color of a range of text.

```
color = self.text_buffer.create_tag("highlight", foreground=self._highlight_text())
self.text_buffer.apply_tag_by_name("highlight", startIter, endIter)
```

This code currently changes the color of the text in the given range, but it changes as soon as the code is executed. I want this change of color to be gradual instead of immediate. It would be cool to make it be some kind of animation, like transition the color from left to right in a set amount of time, or to make the color transluscent and gradually making it more opaque. How can I do it?

Comment: You might want to read up on CSS.